# Is reading a single record always an atomic operation?

Tags: concurrency, isolation-level

Is reading a single record always an atomic operation?

I mean, when e.g. a read (select) and write (update) query are simultaneously carried out on the same record, is it possible for the read operation to read and inconsistent record? (some field values from the old version of that record and some new values resulting from the write operation be returned)

Answer (score 2):

In an ACID compliant database it is atomic

Comment: MySQL InnoDB/MyISAM? (without using transaction)

Comment: InnoDB is ACID compliant and MyISAM is not.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html and (from Rackspace) http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-engines-myisam-vs-innodb